# How to solve NodeSchool's Duplexer challenge without the Duplexer package

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream, duplex

### Problem (downloadable from [nodeschool.io/#stream-adventure](http://nodeschool.io/#stream-adventure))

> Write a program that exports a function that spawns a process from a
>   `cmd` string and an `args` array and returns a single duplex stream
>   joining together the stdin and stdout of the spawned process. There is
>   a very handy module you can use here: duplexer. The duplexer module
>   exports a single function `duplexer(writable, readable)` that joins
>   together a writable stream and readable stream into a single,
>   readable/writable duplex stream.

### Official solution

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
var duplexer = require('duplexer');

module.exports = function (cmd, args) {
    var ps = spawn(cmd, args);
    return duplexer(ps.stdin, ps.stdout);
};
```

This code basically does the following:

```
var spawn = require("child_process").spawn,
    Stream = require("stream");

module.exports = function (cmd, args) {
    var ps = spawn(cmd, args),
        stream = new Stream();
    stream.write = function (chunk, enc, cb) { ps.stdin.write(chunk, enc, cb); }
    stream.end = function (chunk, enc, cb) { ps.stdin.end(chunk, enc, cb); }
    ps.stdout.on("data", function (chunk) { stream.emit("data", chunk); });
    ps.stdout.on("end", function () { stream.emit("end"); });
    return stream;
};
```

### Solution without the Duplexer package

I tried to solve the problem by inheriting from the [`Duplex`](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_duplex) class:

```
var spawn = require("child_process").spawn,
    Stream = require("stream");

require("util").inherits(Dx, Stream.Duplex);
function Dx(stdin, stdout) {
    Stream.Duplex.call(this);
    this.stdin = stdin;
    this.stdout = stdout;
}
Dx.prototype._write = function (chunk, enc, cb) { this.stdin.write(chunk, enc, cb); };
Dx.prototype._read = function (size) { return this.stdout.read(size); };

module.exports = function (cmd, args) {
    var ps = spawn(cmd, args),
        stream = new Dx(ps.stdin, ps.stdout);
    return stream;
};
```

When I test this (`stream-adventure verify program.js`), the test program prints the `ACTUAL vs. EXPECTED` table (it looks correct), but after that it gets stucked. What's wrong with my code? Thank you for your help.

### Update

Adding this line solves the problem:

```
Dx.prototype.end = function (chunk, enc, cb) { this.stdin.end(chunk, enc, cb); }
```

So the question is, why isn't it enough to implement the `_read` and `_write` methods?

Comment: what do you mean by "it gets stucked"? the process does not end? or something else happens?

Comment: Yes. The test program "freezes" (I mean, it does not do anything) after printing the table. UPDATE: It turned out that the `end` method was missing.

Answer (score 0):

[`process.stdin`](http://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_stdin) persists after all the other actions are done, that's why the process does not end. To let the process end, usually, the method `process.stdin.pause()` is used, because you can resume it after this.

You can try to override the `.end()` method, but it is not a good practice, better practices would be:

**#1** If you know the ending message to be written for this stream you should add `.resume()` method inside the `._write()` implementation:

```
dstream._write = function (chunk, encoding, callback) {

    this.stdin.write(chunk, encoding, callback);

    if (someConditionToEnd) {
        this.stdin.pause();
    }
};
```

**#2** Listen to end event:

```
/*
inside the stream prototype constructor
*/

this.on('end', function () {
    this.stdin.pause();
});
```